# Primefaces cellEditor displaying strange behaviour

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tablecelleditor

I am trying to implement primefaces celleditor. 
Below is the jsf code

```
 <h:form id="FeesManagementForm">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
                <h:panelGroup id="feesHeadCreatePG">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateFeesHeadsLabel_feesHeadName}" for="feesHeadName" />
                        <p:inputText id="feesHeadName" value="#{feeManagementController.selectedFH.feesHeadName}" title="#{bundle.CreateFeesHeadsTitle_feesHeadName}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateFeesHeadsRequiredMessage_feesHeadName}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateFeesHeadsLabel_feesPayableFrequency}" for="feesPayableFrequency" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="feesPayableFrequency" value="#{feeManagementController.selectedFH.feesPayableFrequency}" required="true" requiredMessage="Frequency is required">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Monthly" itemValue="Monthly" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yearly" itemValue="Yearly" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Quaterly" itemValue="Quaterly" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateFeesHeadsLabel_feesDescription}" for="feesDescription" />
                        <p:inputText id="feesDescription" value="#{feeManagementController.selectedFH.feesDescription}" title="#{bundle.CreateFeesHeadsTitle_feesDescription}" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{feeManagementController.createFH}" value="#{bundle.Save}" update="feesHeadCreatePG datalist" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{feeManagementController.itemsFH}" var="item"
                     editable="true" 
                     paginator="true"
                     rowKey="#{item.feesHeadId}"
                     rows="10"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                     >
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{feeManagementController.onRowEditFH}" update="FeesManagementForm datalist" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{feeManagementController.onRowCancelFH}" update="FeesManagementForm datalist" />
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFeesHeadsTitle_feesHeadName}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.feesHeadName}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{item.feesHeadName}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFeesHeadsTitle_feesPayableFrequency}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.feesPayableFrequency}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="feesPayableFrequency" value="#{item.feesPayableFrequency}" required="true" requiredMessage="Frequency is required">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Monthly" itemValue="Monthly" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yearly" itemValue="Yearly" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Quaterly" itemValue="Quaterly" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFeesHeadsTitle_feesDescription}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.feesDescription}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput3" value="#{item.feesDescription}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:32px">
       <p:rowEditor />
   </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panelGrid>      
        </h:form>
```

When i try to click on the edit button, all the datatable cell become editable as expected. But as soon as I click on the save button, the jsf page rendered is as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D68mI.jpg)

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I realised that the getter method of the list was getting not written properly. The list was getting refreshed during process.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post beans also in your questions